# VBA Web Scraping- scraping a list of "hrefs"

Tags: vba, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I want to scrape a list of names which are included in a clickable link. However I don´t get a result. In a second step I would like to create per title a new tab.

It´s would be great if someone could give me a hint what´s wrong in my coding and how could I optimize it.

Thanks for your help in advance!

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Teams()

Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim li_all As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim li_single As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate "https://www.examplexyz.de/"
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:07"))
    
    Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
    Set li_all = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("icon_holder")
    
    For i = 0 To li_all.Length - 1
    
        li_single = li_all(0).getElementsByTagName("li").Item(i).innerText
        Debug.Print li_single
          
    Next
    
    IE.Quit

End Sub

'Helper function to get a child (of `obj`) element's text using its className
'  (only handles a single instance but could be extended)
Function classText(obj As Object, classname As String) As String
    Dim els As Object
    Set els = obj.getElementsByClassName(classname)
    If els.Length > 0 Then
        classText = els(0).innerText
    Else
        classText = "[not found]"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: First thing is to remove `i = i + 1`. `i` is your counter variable in the for-loop and is incremented automatically. In a `For`-Loop, *never* modify the counter by yourself. In any programming language.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I have corrected my coding. Maybe do you have any idea how I can loop over the li-elements? I have seen in different posts that it´s possible by `querySelectorAll`. But my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution how to read all link texts using queryselectorall. But currently I get the link texts multiple times, because the link text exists multiple times in the lower levels.

How do I manage to read out only the first level of the "li"?

```
Sub Neu()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, nodeList As Object, OutputString As String, currentItem As Long
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = False
objIE.Navigate "https://www.examplexyz.de/"
    
Do While objIE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

Set nodeList = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll("div.icon_holder a")

For currentItem = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
OutputString = nodeList.Item(currentItem)
Debug.Print currentItem & " " & OutputString

Next currentItem

End Sub
```

Comment: `div.icon_holder > ul > li > a` ?

Comment: Thanks!  I have two additional questions: I have seen in another posting you use "css query" to check which output you will get for a special query selector. For example I insert the queryselector "div.icon_holder > ul > li > a"  and I get listed of all relevant hrefs. It looks really helpful, can you explain which tool you use for it? I it an addon? In addition I wonder in which cases it´s the best way to use "queryselectorall"?